# Need assistance playing sound on uiactionsheet tap

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, uiactionsheet

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
if(actionSheet.tag == 2) {
        if(buttonIndex != actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex) {
            NSString *s = [actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
            NSString *soundFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:s ofType:@"m4a"];
            NSURL *soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFile];
            AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:soundUrl error:nil];
            player.numberOfLoops = 0;
            [player play];
        }
    }
}
```

When I place a breakpoint on `[player play];` and step over, iPhone is playing the sound. Without breakpoint its not playing the sound. Why this is happening?

Comment: Because your player is being deallocated (since you created it as a local variable) as soon as the method goes out of scope. Create a strong property for player, and it will work properly.

Comment: @rdelmar Thanks for replying, please post it as answer so I can vote and select as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think your project is enabled ARC.

When ARC enable local variables destroy after method execution.

So you have to declare your AVAudioPlayre object as global.

It will maintain your object till view destroy.